# PHP shmom - can write, can't read

Tags: php, memory

I am exploring using sh_mop to exchange short messages between an error logger and another script that is periodically checked by another server.  sh_mop seems incredibly simple so I wrote a spot of test code

**The Logger**

```
$str = time()."\0";
$shmid = shmop_open(1091,'c',0666,strlen($str));
echo "$shmid\n";
$writes = shmop_write($shmid,$str,0);
echo "$writes\n";
```

**The Log Reader**

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$shmid = shmop_open(1091,'a',0,0);
if ($shmid)
{
 $size = shmop_size($shmid);
 $str = shmop_read($shmid,0,$size);
 shmop_delete($shmid);
 echo trim($str);
}
flush();
```

Calling the logger from my browser I get the expected responses.  However, when I call the log reader script nothing happens.  On examining my server error logs I find

```
PHP Warning:  shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment
```

It is not at all clear to me why this should be happening.  The examples I find use ftok to fix the shmop key for shmop_open.  However, I require a pre-defined key in order to be able to access the same memory block from the log reader script.

I am using shmop becuase it is adequate for the purpose - a Memcache solution would work but seems OTT.  What if anything am I doing wrong here? I'd much appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP documentation is less than crystal clear in its explanation of just what the *key* in

```
shmop_open(key,flags,mode,size)
```

should be.  It turns out that you cannot just use a numeric key at random.  The only way this works is if the key is generated via [ftok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftok.php).  I ended up using

```
$key = ftok('shmop.txt','t')
```

in both my logger & log reader scripts where shmop.txt is a 0 byte file in the same folder.  This works!